# PHP curl for PUT request to send video file to vimeo

Tags: php, curl, vimeo-api

To upload video to vimeo we have to use put request with binary data as in  [document](https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced/upload#streaming-step3) .I was trying to send put request from `php curl lib`

My code is below :

```
$params = array_merge($params, array(
            'client_id' => $this->_consumer_key,
            'file_data'       => '@'.$file_path // don't include the file in the signature
        ));
$file_path ="/a.mp4";
$fp = fopen($file_path, 'r');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 86400); // 1 Day Timeout
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($file_path));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
$rsp=curl_exec ($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch))
    print_r( curl_error($ch));

curl_close ($ch);
```

But It is not showing any error.If I'm printing res it gives "malformed" .Any suggestions ?

Comment: Normally there will be authentication when you are trying to reach a site like vimeo.

Comment: I have edited and added $params parameter which has client Id

Answer (score 0):

A lot of things are missing from this. If  you plan on sticking with PHP I recommend you just use the official PHP library : https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-php-lib

If you still want to do it yourself, you need a couple of things.

1. Authenticate using OAuth 1.0a - https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced#oauth
2. Follow the Upload documentation https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced/upload